# Kill old php cron script

Tags: php, cron, process

After running ps aux | grep php, I found about 10 php scripts ran by cron that have started over a week ago and are hanging.

Each script usually take 40 seconds to complete.

I have set ini_set('max_execution_time', 60) hoping it would terminate after 60 seconds.

How can I diagnose what is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use tools like strace, ltrace to see what a particular hanged script process is doing. Also lsof if it's stuck doing something on a fd (like a blocking select).